# Strange issue in converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

While converting this line of code from

```
a[0] = (a[0]! as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

to

```
a[0] = (a[0]! as NSArray).filtered(using:predicate)
```

I got an error 'Generic parameter `Element` could not be inferred'
However changing the function was the suggestion of XCode.
What can be a problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: Strange code. Use Swift `Array` and native `filter` function.

Comment: @vadian but filtered also is Swift function and was suggested by XCode

Comment: The Xcode migrator is not a code optimizer. It just tries to update the existing code to the Swift 3 syntax.

Comment: Log `a` and show where you initialize it.

Comment: What type is `a[0]`? There is not enough information in this question. You should probably just use `a[0].filter(predicate)`.

Comment: @jtbandes it is Dictionary<Int, Array<AnyObject>>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your `a` is declared as `Dictionary<Int, Array<AnyObject>>`, then the cause of the error is obvious. (Though the error message is misleading and confusing, take it as just saying "there's some type-related error".)

Check the result type of `filtered(using:)` method of `NSArray`:

[`filtered(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1411033-filtered)

> ## Declaration
>
> ```
> func filtered(using predicate: NSPredicate) -> [Any]
> ```

It returns `[Any]` -- `Array<Any>`. So you cannot assign the result to `a[0]`, which needs to be `[AnyObject]` -- `Array<AnyObject>`.

You may need to write something like this:

```
a[0] = (a[0]! as NSArray).filtered(using:predicate) as Array<AnyObject>
```

As already commented, try to use Swift `Array`s `filter(_:)` method as much as possible, to avoid this sort of tragedy...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Errors are gone now. The error message was quite ambigous1